# Proof of Banach-Alaoglu theorem by Douglas

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am struggling to understand a step in the proof of the Banach-Alaoglu theorem (1.23) given in Douglas - Banach Algebra Techniques in Operator Theory. Here is the relevant section of the book:
[image]

I am having trouble understanding why the highlighted portions are true. This feels like the usual "linear maps are determined by their images on the basis," except there is no basis here. I imagine the fact that $\lVert\varphi_1\rVert,\lVert\varphi_2\rVert\le1$ must be relevant, but I do not see how. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two linear functionals $f$ and $g$ are equal on the closed unit ball they are equal everywhere: For any $x$ with $\|x\| >1$ we have $f(x)=\|x\|f(\frac x {\|x\|})=\|x\|g(\frac x {\|x\|})=g(x)$ by linearity of $f$ and $g$.

The product topology is the topology of convergence of each coordinate  and weak* convergence is the topology of convergence at each point $x$.

Comment: I don't really understand the second part of your answer. I know that weak* convergence is the same as pointwise convergence, and I know that characterization of the product topology, but I am struggling to see why the highlighted portion is true. For example, we are comparing pointwise convergence on $X$ with pointwise convergence on $(X)_1$. Is this resolved by the first part of your answer?

Comment: @Victor Exactly. As in the first part convergence at each of the closed unit disk implies convergence for points outside the disk also.

Comment: It is clear now, thank you.